# How to iterate over a list of IDs to produce URLs for each ID every time?

Tags: python, list, function, loops, url

I've got a list of IDs which I want to pass through the URLs to collect the data on the comments. But I'm kinda of newb and when I'm trying to iterate over the list, I'm getting only one url and consequently data for one comment. Can someone, please, explain me what's wrong with my code and how to get URLs for all IDs in a list and consequently collect the data for all comments?

```
comments_from_reddit = ['fkkmga7', 'fkkgxtj', 'fkklfx3', ...]
def getPushshiftData():
    for ID in range(len(comments_from_reddit)):
        url = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?ids={}'.format(comments_from_reddit[ID])
        print(url)
        req = requests.get(url)
        data = json.loads(req.text)
        return data['data']
data = getPushshiftData()
```

**Output I'm getting:** https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?ids=fkkmga7

I will really appreciate any help on my issue. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You're returning in the first iteration of your loop. Put the data in a list and return the list after the loop. You're also creating an unnecessary `range`, you can simply loop ofter the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
comments_from_reddit = ['fkkmga7', 'fkkgxtj', 'fkklfx3', ...]

def getPushshiftData():
    result = list()
    for ID in range(len(comments_from_reddit)):
        url = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?ids={}'.format(comments_from_reddit[ID])
        print(url)
        req = requests.get(url)
        data = json.loads(req.text)
        result.append( data['data'] )

    return result

data = getPushshiftData()
```